# Spark Dataframe - Method to take row as input & dataframe has output

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to write a method that iterates all the rows from DF2 and generate a Dataframe based on some conditions.

Here is the inputs DF1 & DF2 :

```
val df1Columns = Seq("Eftv_Date","S_Amt","A_Amt","Layer","SubLayer")
val df2Columns = Seq("Eftv_Date","S_Amt","A_Amt")
var df1 = List(
      List("2016-10-31","1000000","1000","0","1"),
      List("2016-12-01","100000","950","1","1"),
      List("2017-01-01","50000","50","2","1"),
      List("2017-03-01","50000","100","3","1"),
      List("2017-03-30","80000","300","4","1")
    )
      .map(row =>(row(0), row(1),row(2),row(3),row(4))).toDF(df1Columns:_*)

+----------+-------+-----+-----+--------+
| Eftv_Date|  S_Amt|A_Amt|Layer|SubLayer|
+----------+-------+-----+-----+--------+
|2016-10-31|1000000| 1000|    0|       1|
|2016-12-01| 100000|  950|    1|       1|
|2017-01-01|  50000|   50|    2|       1|
|2017-03-01|  50000|  100|    3|       1|
|2017-03-30|  80000|  300|    4|       1|
+----------+-------+-----+-----+--------+

val df2 = List(
  List("2017-02-01","0","400")
).map(row =>(row(0), row(1),row(2))).toDF(df2Columns:_*)

+----------+-----+-----+
| Eftv_Date|S_Amt|A_Amt|
+----------+-----+-----+
|2017-02-01|    0|  400|
+----------+-----+-----+
```

Now I need to write a method that filters DF1 based on the Eftv_Date values from each row of DF2.
For example, first row of df2.Eftv_date=Feb 01 2017, so need to filter df1 having records Eftv_date less than or equal to Feb 01 2017.So this will generate 3 records as below:

Expected Result :

```
+----------+-------+-----+-----+--------+
| Eftv_Date|  S_Amt|A_Amt|Layer|SubLayer|
+----------+-------+-----+-----+--------+
|2016-10-31|1000000| 1000|    0|       1|
|2016-12-01| 100000|  950|    1|       1|
|2017-01-01|  50000|   50|    2|       1|
+----------+-------+-----+-----+--------+
```

I have written the method as below and called it using map function.

```
def transformRows(row: Row ) = {
  val dateEffective = row.getAs[String]("Eftv_Date")
  val df1LayerMet    =  df1.where(col("Eftv_Date").leq(dateEffective))
  df1 = df1LayerMet
  df1
} 

val x = df2.map(transformRows)
```

But while calling this I am facing this error:

```
Error:(154, 24) Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
val x = df2.map(transformRows)
```

Note : We can implement this using join , But I need to implement a custom scala method to do this , since there were a lot of transformations involved. For simplicity I have mentioned only one condition.

Comment: you cannot use dataframes in remote code (in transformRows)

Comment: if df2 is small, you could collect it (resulting in a Array[Row]), then map to transformRows, then union all the dataframes.

Answer (score 2):

Seems you need a non-equi join:

```
df1.alias("a").join(
    df2.select("Eftv_Date").alias("b"), 
    df1("Eftv_Date") <= df2("Eftv_Date")          // non-equi join condition
).select("a.*").show
+----------+-------+-----+-----+--------+
| Eftv_Date|  S_Amt|A_Amt|Layer|SubLayer|
+----------+-------+-----+-----+--------+
|2016-10-31|1000000| 1000|    0|       1|
|2016-12-01| 100000|  950|    1|       1|
|2017-01-01|  50000|   50|    2|       1|
+----------+-------+-----+-----+--------+
```

Comment: I understood we can do an non-equi join. But I need to handle via a "custom method call" which includes a lot of transformations

Comment: *You can not nest distributed data set*. By nesting the transformation as you did, for each map you return a data frame which is distributed in nature, which would cause problems. So it depends what you are trying to do, you possibly have to figure out a way to transform the data using a join or something similar.

Comment: Just fyi, if you want to transform the match for each row in `df2`, one possibility could be to create a row id for `df2`, join with `df1`, then group by this `id` and apply your transformation.

Comment: I did not get that. Basically I need to loop all the records of df1 , perform some transformations based on the values from df2.